# smooth look at only on x and y

Tags: unity, camera, rotate

i'm using the script down below to make my camera look at mouse x and y position, and it has a limitation for my camera rotation.the problem is the way my camera rotates is not smooth at all.is there any way to make it smoothly look at position on x and y?

```
    rotationX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityX;

    rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(rotationX, minimumX, maximumX);

    rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityY ;

    rotationY = Mathf.Clamp(rotationY, minimumY, maximumY);

    transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-rotationY , rotationX, 0);
```

Comment: You might want to add an animated gif to show the issue and what you consider "not smooth".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are rotating it on a fixed time step.  Unity's `Update` method (which I assume you are using) uses a variable time step.  This means you have two options:

Normally you would perform your physics update in `FixedUpdate`, but input does not work in `FixedUpdate`.  This means you need to multiply by your time step, AKA the duration of the previous frame.  Your new code would look like such:

```
private void Update()
{
    rotationX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityX * Time.deltaTime;
    rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(rotationX, minimumX, maximumX);
    rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityY * Time.deltaTime;
    rotationY = Mathf.Clamp(rotationY, minimumY, maximumY);
    transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-rotationY , rotationX, 0);
}
```

With this new code, you will also need to increase your sensitivity variables.

Comment: Because Mouse X and Mouse Y are position deltas *since the last frame*, they're already smaller on short frames and longer on long frames, assuming a constant mouse speed in both cases. [So this is one case where it's actually *not* correct to add an extra `* Time.deltaTime`](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/171901/39518) as that double-corrects and can introduce unwanted artifacts. Also, it's not true that input doesn't work in FixedUpdate (this is a popular misconception - try it!), we just have to be cautious how we use it, as input is updated once per frame not once per fixed timestep.